# FFMpeg Compress WebM - VP9 with alpha channel

Tags: ffmpeg, webm

I'm looking for a way compress a quicktime .mov in animation format with alpha to VP9. I've tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -i Elephant_01.mov -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuva444p output3.webm
```

but I get an `incompatible pixel format...` error.

any suggestions, as far as I can tell VP9 -should- support the yuva444p format. Or is there another tool that works?

Comment: possibly also ask on superuser...

Comment: @LordNeckbeard what do you think we should do here...between the two of us we don't have enough votes...should I keep leaving suggestions to re-ask on superuser, with a vote to close?  I think SO just did some change that will make it even less likely that these will accrue enough votes fast enough to be migrated... [?]

Comment: @rogerdpack I don't know, and I don't see a solution. I guess we can just answer them.

Comment: OK so @LordNeckbeard answer them *and* close do you think?  No comment like "this typically belongs on superuser" or a comment too? :)

Answer (score 2):

Since [2016-07-13](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/acca56d9629b7fc158ce188190d22314c3d92c39), it's possible to encode *VP9/webm* videos with alpha channel (*VP9a*) so the command you use here will now work (assuming you got a copy of **ffmpeg** compiled after that date). Nevertheless, **ffmpeg** will complain:

```
Incompatible pixel format 'yuva444p' for codec 'libvpx-vp9',
auto-selecting format 'yuva420p'
```

The final pixel format of the video will be `yuva420p`, but it will be fully functional.